# How to update the huge Json data which is available in Elastic Search ( Kibana ) using python

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, kibana

I tried to update the json data in kibana throwing an exception due to huge data.

```
"statusCode": 413,
"error": "Request Entity Too Large",
"message": "Payload content length greater than maximum allowed: 1048576"
```

How to update this huge json using python programatically instead of direct updation in kibana? Any one can suggest to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Code to connect kibana using python:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
es = Elasticsearch("https://pd-analytics.example.com")
if es.ping():
    print("Yeah connect")
else:
    print("couldn't connect")


from elasticsearch_dsl import Search
from elasticsearch_dsl import connections
connections.create_connection(hosts=['https://pd-analytics.example.com'])
s = Search(index="projectdetails")
response = s.scan()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
es = Elasticsearch("https://pd-analytics.example.com/")
if es.ping():
    print("Yeah connect")
else:
    print("couldn't connect")

import json   
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
#from . libraryupload import connect_elasticsearch,connect_elasticsearch_live,connect_elasticsearch_demo
es=connect_elasticsearch()
with open('update_json.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    key = "LXCL125EJM8FCI"
    replyFromes = es.index(index='projectexport', doc_type='doc', id=key, body=data)
    print(replyFromes)
    print(replyFromes['result'])
```

I have updated the json data in local and then updated in kibana using python.

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting the limit set in `kibana.yml`. The default value is set to `1048576`, which is what you see in your response. You can edit the `server.maxPayloadBytes` field to increase the limit to satisfy your criteria. You can look at other options available in the configuration file [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html).

Comment: Any way to update via python for security purpose instead of changing the configurations.

Comment: Can you add which library you're using to access Kibana? And some of the code you are using.